# Android: Two columns (50% to 50%)

Tags: java, android, xml, adk

I am newbie to Android development (in fact I have downloaded ADK today) and I want to create simple setting page with two columns. In first column should be the text and in second column should be button/slider/etc.

My problem is that when I use LinearLayout, only FULL WIDTH TEXT is visible. Columns are shown "outside" of screen on the right side of text.

This is how the screen should look like.

```
/-----------------\
| FULL WIDTH TEXT |
|                 |
| Column1 Column2 |
| Column1 Column2 |
\-----------------/
```

There is content of my XML file:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_settings_hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/settings_hint" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_motion_sensor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkbox_motion_sensor" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_light_sensor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkbox_light_sensor" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_shake_sensor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkbox_shake_sensor" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_motion_sensor_sensitivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I set the inner layouts to be drawn on bottom of TextView? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your items are being set to the right of the screen, because your root linear layout has the property of orientation horizontally, so, the first element is being shown, and the next element is being pushed to the right of the screen. In order to fix that specific issue, just change property to vertically and you will notice that your inner layouts are stocking all the elements one on top of another, in order to get the "two" colums effect, you need to create another horizontal layout after the first text view, that way you are telling the inflater that, the first text will be set on top of your horizontal columns. Just as advice, what you are trying to do could be simply done either with TableLayout or RelativeLayout, you should take a look on them...

Regards!

Comment: If I change the roots `android:orientation` to `vertical` I do not even see the "blue borders" of inner layouts outside of screen (They are visible with `horizontal`).

Comment: hehe, you are complicating too much a simple design, one of the golden rules of android is using the proper layout that fits your needs, because it could cost performance to overkill views creation, take a look on tablelayout, that will do exactly what you want in a extremly simple manner, http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/

Comment: After change of roots orientation to `horizontal` and adding additional LinearLayout after text it works perfectly fine! Thank you.On the other hand you suggested to use TableLayout. I have read that TableLayout is designed for cases when you need deal with different sizes of table cells. It is not my case. Thats why I did not use this solution.Could you provide me an example of using RelativeLayout? I have tryed it before LinearLayout, but every example I found use LinearLayout.